# visual studio build tools v120

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Hi I'm using visual studio 2017 and trying to build a solution which contains projects made in visual studio 2013. When trying to build the solution, I am given an error that I need v120 build tools. I installed the build tools, but the issue remains.

The message:

error MSB8020: The build tools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found. To build using the v120 build tools, please install v120 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is open the Project Properties dialog on the Project menu when you have the project open in Visual Studio 2017. Under Configuration Properties -> General, change "Platform Toolset" to one of the available ones on your system.