# Adding a build tools with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have visual studio 2017 but I want to compile a project that use the v120
I install the build tool 
but how I can let the vs 2017 compile using it ? 
it's same question here [visual studio build tools v120](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54790022/visual-studio-build-tools-v120)
but the answer that given as menu follow is deprecated now

Comment: Hi, how did you install Build tool v120(Visual Studio 2013)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have visual studio 2017 but I want to compile a project that use the
> v120 I install the build tool but how I can let the vs 2017 compile
> using it ?

**V120 Build Tool** is a VS2013 build tool for C++ project. And l wonder if you installed the [Build Tool for VS2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760).

**Please note the info about it**:

*If you don't have Visual Studio installed on your computer, you can use Build Tools 2013 to build managed applications. The Visual Basic and C# compilers are also included in this download. (In earlier versions, these tools were included in the stand-alone .NET Framework.)*

Therefore, it does not support compiling **C++** projects, which means that the **V120** compilation tool for C++ projects is not available through the build tool for VS2013.

**Solution**

You should install [Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202013) in parallel on your computer. As part of VS2013, currently there is no a standalone installation package for V120 build tool.

So when you install it ,you can use **V120** build toolset in VS2017.

Comment: "there is no a standalone installation package for V120 build tool" and yet you include a link to buildTools_full.exe...